# Problems updating a data source with data adapter update

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, dataset

First off, I've only started working with databases and c# so I could be making a really stupid mistake here so apologies in advance. I'm connected to a SQL server express database and can read from it fine, however whenever I have updated my DataSet to add new columns and then try to update the data source it wont update successfully. Code below:

```
        DataColumn newColumn;
        SqlCommandBuilder cmdBuild = new SqlCommandBuilder(_myAdapt);

        foreach (String s in myList)
        {
            newColumn = new DataColumn(s, System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
            _myData.Tables["Table1"].Columns.Add(newColumn);
        }

        _myAdapt.Update(_myData, "Table1");
```

Anyone got any suggestions as to why this wont work? I've debugged it and the data set is definitely being updated with the new columns but I cant seem to update the data source.

Thanks for any responses.

Comment: What error please? And are you trying to update more columns that actually exist in the database?

Comment: Yeah I was trying to update more columns than exist in the database, I have two text huge files that I was trying to create a new table around. One of them contains a list of about 700,000 labels that I want to map to columns. The other contains test results for about 1500 people that I was going to bulk insert once the columns had been added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does that column exist in the database (and just not in your database), or are you trying to ALTER the table definition in the database using the dataset.

I don't believe the 2nd of the above is possible.  Your dataset needs to have a column structure to match that of the database table that you're updating.  You can however add as many rows as you like to the dataset and they will all INSERT to the database fine.

If you feel you have a need to add columns to your table at run-time I'd suggest revisiting your data-model.  Where possible your column definitions should be be unchanging over time, to represent the main attributes of the data entities you're storing.

Comment: Yeah it's the second of those two that I was trying to do. I guess I'll just have to rethink my approach. Thanks for the answer.